# Why does my negative slicing in Python not work?

Tags: python-2.7

I am new to Python and have read several tutorials on slicing however the examples I run in idle don't seem to return what I expect it to. For example I have assigned the follow list to the variable `a`

`a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]`

Now I understand slicing to be as `[number I want to include:number up to and don't want to include:step]`

Hence if I do `a[1]`, I would expect `1`. If I do `a[1:3]`, it would be `1,2`

Now if I do `a[-1]`, I get `9` BUT if I do `a[-1:-5]`, I get nothing. All I see is `[]`. why is that? I would expect to see `9,8,7,6`

I am running Python 2.7 on Windows 7 Professional

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, you would need to add in the `step` argument in order to get what you want:

```
In [1]: a=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

In [2]: a[-1:-5:-1]
Out[2]: [9, 8, 7, 6]
```

And if you want to save a bit more space, you can omit the first argument:

```
In [3]: a[:-5:-1]
Out[3]: [9, 8, 7, 6]
```

The way that Python handles the 'negative' slices is that it adds then `len` of the object to the negative number. So when you say In `a[-1:-5]`, it is basically saying `a[(-1+10):(-5+10)]`, which equals `a[9:5]`, and since `start`/`end` refers to all characters between the two (moving 'forward' through the list), it doesn't return anything (hence your blank list). You can see this by doing something like:

```
In [5]: a[-5:9]
Out[5]: [5, 6, 7, 8]

In [6]: a[5:9]
Out[6]: [5, 6, 7, 8]
```

You get the same result with the negative and positive indices, since `-5 + 10 = 5`.

Providing the -1 `step` argument tells it to start at the first element but move backwards from the start position.

Comment: Why do I need to add the `step` argument? I would thought it would automatically know where `-1` or `-5` start and end

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey Yeah, it is a bit strange at first. Added an update - does that make sense?

Comment: That makes sense now. So when using negative ranges, does it add 1 to the total number of characters e.g. In my example I have 9 characters and if Python is doing `a[-1+10]:[-5+10]`, I would imagine it adding 1 to the total count of characters.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey I believe you actually have 10 characters (0-9) :) Also, as you probably know, the upper bound is not included in the slice, so `a[1:2]` would return `[1]`, if that helps.

Comment: That's correct if I start the `len` count from 1. I was counting from 0.

Comment: @PeanutsMonkey If you have 9 characters, `a[-1:-5]` will be `a[8:4]`, which will still return a blank list if you don't provide the step. Then `len` will be whatever you get from running `len(a)`, regardless of where you start/stop the slice. Does that make sense? Sorry if I'm muddling the issue :)

Answer (score 2):

I think it's good to think of splicing as not the numbers themselves, but pointers to the indices.

```
                      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                      | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
                      +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
                        0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9
                      -10  -9  -8  -7  -6  -5  -4  -3  -2  -1
```

Therefore, when you're slicing `a[-1:-5]`, you're starting from index 9 and going down to index 5. Nothing is in that slice. If you do `a[-5:-1]`, then you will start from index 5 up to index 9.

RocketDonkey is right - if you want `[9, 8, 7, 6]`, you need to step backwards.