# Negative Slicing in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

quiz question :

```
a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

result for :

```
print a([-1:-5])
```

I don't know the actual output for this operation please update.

Comment: These type of questions are not well received in SO.

Comment: It is faster to run it than to ask for answers

Comment: Above print statement will throw an error. Syntax is not correct. Please check the question again.

Comment: @PrashantKumar It wouldn't throw an error. Please refer to docs.

Comment: @Ch3steR see this : `Python 3.6.8 (default, Apr  9 2019, 04:59:38) 
[GCC 8.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> a=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
>>> print a([-1:-5])
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    print a([-1:-5])
            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`

Comment: @PrashantKumar That's because OP wrote `a([-1:-5])` whereas it should be written as `a[-1:-5]` and `a[-1:-5]` is valid.

Comment: I think what he wanted is a[-5:], which then gives [6, 7, 8, 9, 10]. Who knows..

Comment: @Ch3steR I don't want to guess what he has written. I can fix it if I want to,  by guessing everything. We should not guess here instead ask user to correct question by pointing out the problem in question.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: The syntax error comes from the missing parentheses in the call to `print`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13672627/why-does-my-negative-slicing-in-python-not-work

Answer (score 1):

To start with, it's invalid syntax.

But even if you had your syntax correct, it's going to give you an empty array. Because it is not going to slice between -1 to -5, but it will slice between -5 to -1. Imagine that slicing will only work from a smaller number: larger number.

so

```
print(a[-1:-5])
```

will result in

```
[]
```

Whereas

```
print(a[-5:-1])
```

will result in the elements 5th position from the end of the list to the first position from the end of the list which is

```
[6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Comment: `a[-1:-5:-1]` will work. *Imagine that slicing will only work from a smaller number: larger number.* This doesn't make sense.